# October CMS | Creating a portfolio with 'show more' but struggling with twig

Tags: html, twig, octobercms

What I would like to achieve is, when there are more than 6 items, the remaining items go into the 'show more' section automatically.

```
{% for item in portfolioItems %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="{{ item.portfolioItemsImage |media }}" alt="">
    <h5>{{item.portfolioItemsTitle}}</h5>
</div>

After 6 items have been displayed above the rest of the items should be shown below.

<!-- HIDDEN -->
<div id="showmore" class="collapse">
    <img src="{{item.portfolioItemsImage|media}}" alt="">
    <h5>{{item.portfolioItemsTitle}}</h5>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#showmore">Show More</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make two loops and use the [slicing techniques](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html):

```
{% for item in portfolioItems[:6] %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="{{ item.portfolioItemsImage|media }}" alt="">
    <h5>{{ item.portfolioItemsTitle }}</h5>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

{% for item in portfolioItems[6:] %}
  <!-- HIDDEN -->
  <div id="showmore" class="collapse">
    <img src="{{ item.portfolioItemsImage|media }}" alt="">
    <h5>{{ item.portfolioItemsTitle }}</h5>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>*Simple demo here: https://twigfiddle.com/6olcw2*</sup>

---

Or you could use the [loop variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) along with a `if`/`else`

```
{% for item in portfolioItems %}
  {% if loop.index <= 6 %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="{{ item.portfolioItemsImage|media }}" alt="">
      <h5>{{ item.portfolioItemsTitle }}</h5>
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <!-- HIDDEN -->
    <div id="showmore" class="collapse">
      <img src="{{ item.portfolioItemsImage|media }}" alt="">
      <h5>{{ item.portfolioItemsTitle }}</h5>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>*Simple demo here: https://twigfiddle.com/6olcw2/2*</sup>